# vote breakout not correct

Tags: bug, vote-count

Before going to the issue, I must say I don't have 1,000 reputation, but the vote breakout working now.

This is what I've got before I clicked the vote ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823352/upvote-downvote)):

> [image]

And this is what I've got after I clicked the vode:

> [image]

It's not as same as the introduction of vote breakout I saw:

> [image]

It's the bug on my account or something? I can't figure out.

Comment: Another great side-effect of that experiment. Confusion among users that just got the vote breakdown privilege -.-

Comment: @Cerbrus that, and the documentation doesn't match up with the current reality. You can't trust what you read right now.

Comment: I think It's not easy to link this post with the original post. By the way, It's worth to notice [CertainPerformance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s [Tampermonkey Script](https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/d16147600ffa63691e88116b5b040f1d) is the best workaround so far in the original post.